# Unresolved function or method in WebStorm Node Coding Assistance

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, intellij-idea, webstorm

I enabled Node coding assistance under "Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Node.js", yet it is not able to resolve `EventEmitter` functions like `on()` when extended to a child and also functions like `fork()` and variables like `isMaster` under node.js cluster module.

Any known bug or resolution tips ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately due to a way `cluster` is defined in `@types/node` its inferred type is `any`, so no completion/resolving is possible:(

[image]

As a workaround, I'd suggest specifying the type explicitly with JSDoc:

```
/**
 * 
 * @type {module:cluster.Cluster}
 */
const cluster = require('cluster');
```